# Отличия в оптимизации C и C++

Tags: c++, c

Какой код компилируется Си и С++, корректно работает, но при этом может отличается по быстродействию вследствие различий стандартов C и C++?

Пример: `malloc(sizeof('x') * 100500)` выделит в `sizeof(int)` раз больше памяти в Си, что теоретически может замедлить программу.

Comment: он может отличаться, если у Вас разные компиляторы и параметры компиляции.

Comment: зачем минусовать?

Comment: с и с++ два, хоть и похожих немного, но достаточно разных языка. И стандарты у них достаточно разные. Поэтому это сравнение немного бессмысленное.

Comment: Есть [тема на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12887700/3240681) про различия в поведении одинакового кода. Вопрос быстродействия можно в каждом отдельном случае оценить. Но это может быть порой бессмысленно, т.к. фактически код хоть и будет выглядеть одинаково, делать будет несколько разные вещи.

Comment: @Abyx ну, корректность работы - понятие не очень чёткое. Например, `auto i = 1.23;`

Comment: Приведённый Вами пимер - это "копейки". Настоящая разница исполнимого модуля, скомпиллированного С++ и С компилляторами для одинакового кода заключается в т.н. "префиксе блока". Этот тот СТАНДАРНЫЙ код, который выполняется, при входе в блок. Для С это порядка 100 инструкций. Для С++ это ГОРАЗДО хуже. В силу его полиморфизма и виртуализации. Могут выполнятся многие тысячи инструкций.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему вопрос озаглавлен "отличия в оптимизации", а затем вдруг приведен пример с разницей в `sizeof('x')`, который к оптимизации никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @Abyx: "Поведение одинаковое"? Если "поведение одинаковое", то и различий в производительности быть не может. Возникнуть в такой ситуации оно может только из-за различий в качестве реализации компиляторов.

Comment: @alexolut: `auto i = 1.23` не является корректным объявлением в С с 1999 года.

Comment: @Sergey: Ни в С, ни в С++ нет никакой необходимости выполнять какой-то скрытый код при "входе в блок", за исключением тех случаев, когда этот блок является телом функции. Может вы имели в виду вход в функцию?

Comment: **нет никакой необходимости выполнять какой-то скрытый код при "входе в блок"** - при входе в ЛЮБОЙ блок выполняется, как минимум, выделение автоматической памяти на стеке...

Answer (score 7):

Если абстрагироваться от вопросов качества реализации компиляторов С vs. С++, то отличаться по быстродействию "один и тот же код" в С и С++ может только в том случае, если он отличается по семантике. То есть "одним и тем же кодом" в такой ситуации он будет только с чисто косметически-визуальной точки зрения.

Можно грубо выехать на различиях в правилах name lookup

```
struct S { int a[10]; };

int main() 
{
  struct Local
  {
    struct S { int a[10000]; } s;
  };

  struct S s = { 0 }; // `sizeof s`???
}
```

В языке С здесь объявляется и обнуляется "большой" объект, а в С++ - "маленький". Но это уж слишком грубо.

Свойство языка С++ бережно сохранять lvalue-ность результатов выражений приведет к тому, что цикл

```
for (unsigned n = sizeof (1 ? "Hello" : "World"); n > 0; --n)
  ;
```

будет выполняться разное количество раз в С и в С++. Это тоже довольно грубый прием.

Далее стоит упомянуть следующее

```
const int N = 10;
int A[N][N][N];
```

В языке С++ это - обычный массив, а в языке С - это Variable Length Array с потенциальными накладными расходами во время выполнения.

Продолжая тему VLA, операнд вот такого `sizeof` в языке С является вычислимым выражением (подразумевая вышеприведенное объявление `A`)

```
unsigned n = sizeof A[rand() % N][rand() % N];
```

И хотя, согласно спецификации языка С, вычисления выражений-индексов в данном случае не требуется (ибо результат от них не зависит), компилятор имеет право их вычислить (GCC, что интересно, вычисляет). В C++ же операнд `sizeof` вычислимым не является никогда, т.е. такой `sizeof` вычисляется во время компиляции и выполнимого кода не порождает.

Ворох мелочей может скрываться в различиях правил sequencing этих языков. То же свойство сохранения lvalue-ности результатов выражений в С++ приводит к тому, что его правила sequencing более строги и ограничивающи, чем аналогичные правила в С. Это теоретически может привести к более эффективному коду в С. (Но придумать пример, где бы это давало осязаемый эффект навскидку непросто.)

Потенциальная необходимость обработки исключений в С++ и раскрутки стека - еще одна причина, по которой практически любой идентичный С и С++ код может быть странслирован менее эффективно в С++.

Comment: Можно про цикл чуть подробнее?

Comment: @alexolut: В С++ так как оба операнда оператора `?:` являются lvalues и имеют одинаковый тип (`const char [6]`), потери lvalue в операторе `?:` не происходит, т.е. результат такого оператора `?:` в С++ имеет тип `const char [6]` и является lvalue. В результате `sizeof` дает размер массива - 6. В языке С, который имеет свойство преобразовывать lvalue к rvalue сразу и без зазрения совести, тип "массив" сразу же будет преобразован к типу "указатель" (`char *`). Результат оператора `?:` имеет тип `char *` и `sizeof` будет давать размер указателя.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически fabs((char)x) и собратья из cmath, имеющие перегрузки для целочисленных типов, могут работать быстрее. Появились в С++11, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: В С есть `<tgmath.h>`, достигающий фактически того же эффекта.